# I have a problem between nodejs express and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

Hi guys i tried to apply bootstrap to my website
When i opened only html file The bootstrap files apply to the html file But when i turned on the express server the bootstrap files don't apply to the html file

[this is an image file of html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPm9Z.jpg)

[and this is express server i caputured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlujt.png)

[this is error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgCFN.png)

this is error log here But i think this is hard to read so let me add image

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/landing-page.min.css?ver=1' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):291 GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/jquery/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):292 GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):195 GET http://localhost:3000/img/testimonials-1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
(index):202 GET http://localhost:3000/img/testimonials-2.jpg 404 (Not Found)
(index):208 GET http://localhost:3000/img/testimonials-3.jpg 404 (Not Found)
3(index):1 GET http://localhost:3000/img/imac-1999636_1920.png 404 (Not Found)
(index):291 GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/jquery/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):292 GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score -1):

You most likely did not configure express correctly.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
```

404 pages might respond with content type text/html.
Your logs say your browser cant load images nor JavaScript files.
Please check out this official documentation.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html